# C/C++ Printing stack bottom to top with recursion

Tags: c, recursion, stack

Hey I am trying to print a "stack" from bottom to top using recusion. Everything in the code is as should and only the print function should be modified. I am not getting any recursion print and unfortunately I do not know why.

```
struct element{
    int i;
    element *next;
};

struct stack{
    element *top;
};

void print(stack *st);

int main(){
    element *e5 = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));
    element *e4 = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));
    element *e3 = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));
    element *e2 = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));
    element *e1 = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));

    e5->i = 5; e5->next = NULL;
    e4->i = 4; e4->next = e5;
    e3->i = 3; e3->next = e4;
    e2->i = 2; e2->next = e3;
    e1->i = 1; e1->next = e2;

    stack start;
    start.top = e1;
    element *e;

    print(&start);

    return 0;
}

void print(stack *st){
    stack nxt;
    nxt.top = st->top->next;
    if (st->top != NULL){
        print(&nxt);
        printf("%i\n", st->top);
    }
    else
        printf("%i\n", st->top->i);
}
```

Thank you for your input!

Comment: I see an access of `st->top->next` followed by a check if `st->top != NULL`. What do you think happens if `st->top == NULL`?

Comment: If it is true I am already past my last element? If thats the case I have to check `if (st->top->next != NULL)`

Comment: And what exactly do you think you accomplish by even declaring `nxt` in your recursive function in the first place, initializing it, like that, and then using it for recursion in this strange way? Pro tip: this should be done without declaring anything, simply by recursing correctly.

Comment: If there is a way to do it without using the declared `nxt` I will try it, Thank you for the input!

Comment: Consider the base case of printing an empty stack: `print(stack{nullptr})`. Think about what should happen and verify it by stepping through that expression in a debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Maybe OP was not allowed to change the signature of `print` either..

Comment: @Botje - I'm not sure which part of my comment suggested changing the signature of `print`. When did you think I was suggesting that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Because `st->top->next` is an `element*`, not a `stack*`, so how would you use a `print(stack *)` to print the rest? Not by destructively changing `st`, I hope?

Answer (score 0):

In your else you have a possible crash on this line:

```
printf("%i\n", st->top->i); //<-- possible crash here
```

You should be more clear about what errors you see from you program.

It looks to me like this will crash the program before anything is printed.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, the program is crashing before anything is printed. Printing works now through changing `if (st->top != NULL)` to `if (st->top->next != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems (see Botje's comment), but also:

```
printf("%i\n", st->top);
```

What is the type of `st->top`? What happens if you print it with format `%i`?

Comment: In this statement I missed the `->i`. And `st->top` should be a pointer of type struct element if I am not mistaken and trying to print with format `%i` would result in undefined behaviour? If not please let me know, I am not that used to working in C and pointers in general yet.

Comment: If you try to print a pointer as %i, it will try to print the pointer as if it is an integer. It would print some integer number which is not useful.  (It is first 4 bytes of the address to which it points.)